# Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows()

Tags: php

This is my code in model..

```
function installed(){
    $query_str = "SHOW TABLES";
    $query = $this->db->query($query_str);
    if($query->num_rows() == 0){
      redirect('install');
    }
}
```

So many questions on StackOverflow but I haven't found any answer related to scenario. So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `num_rows` is not a function, it's a variable. Try `$query->num_rows` instead.

Comment: @Qirel No I'm using PDO it will be a function i think

Comment: `num_rows` is a `mysqli_` variable, not a PDO one. Try [`$query->rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), but that function might not always work with all databases. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that, your `$this->db` is a `mysqli` instance. Hence, making a `->query(...)` call should gives you a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) instance on success. So your `$query` should simply be a `mysqli_result` object, and hence `num_rows` should be a property, not a function at all. You are using it wrong.

Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php. They have a sample code there.

So what Qirel mentioned is correct.